# How to get field value from a model from another model in Odoo?

Tags: odoo, openerp-8, odoo-8

I'm having some trouble to understand how to get field values from another model.

I added a custom field in `res.partner` module by making a custom module:

```
class custom_partner_fields(osv.osv):
_inherit = 'res.partner'

_columns = {
'RTN': fields.char('RTN Numerico'),
}

_defaults = {

}
custom_partner_fields()
```

Then I create a custom xml for the form view when creating a new customer and now I can see `RTN` field in the customer create form.

Now I want this new field to appear  when making a new quotation/sale order.
I would like it to get its value when I select my customer (I believe `onchange` function should be use but don't know how to use that!),so what I did was create a custom module for it:

```
class custom_saleorder_fields(osv.osv):

_inherits = 'sale.order'

_columns = {
'partner_rtn': fields.char('RTN'),
}
custom_saleorder_fields()
```

I believe I need to use something like a function or relational field for this but what I've tried hasn't worked yet.

Then, I created the custom view form the sale order form view and adds my `partner_field`.

Now, I would like to know how can I access the specific `RTN` value from `res.partner` module from `custom_saleorder_fields` based on the selected customer.

On the other hand, the main purpose of this new value is to displayed in the sale workflow and also print it in a report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add relational field in sale order model.
Before applying code you should refer that documentation of odoo,

In the [Odoo Field Doc](http://odoo-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/03_module_dev_02.html#fields-introduction) you will know how fields.related works.

```
class custom_saleorder_fields(osv.osv):
    _inherits = 'sale.order'

    _columns = {
        'partner_rtn': fields.related('partner_id','RTN',type="char",relation="res.partner",string="RTN",store=True,readonly=True),
    }
custom_saleorder_fields()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.... this worked for me. Now I know how to use relations in odoo.

Answer (score 1):

bring modelA fields in modelB by relatiional fields 
eg use many2one field in another model :

from openerp import models, fields, api

class partsproviderclass(models.Model):

```
_name='partsprovider.vechicle'
#_rec_name='parts_provider'

id=fields.Integer()
parts_provider=fields.Many2many('supplier.car', string="Parts provider")
parts_name=fields.Many2many('selection.selection',string="Parts Name")
parts_price=fields.Float(string="Price of the Part")
```

class selectionsxample(models.Model):
    _name='selection.selection'

```
name=fields.Char('name',required=True) 
value=fields.Char('value',required=True)
```